# What's the meaning of these military terms?

Tags: meaning

I want to find out the meaning of these military terms:

> 1. from the edge
> 2. tactical edge
> 3. the deployed user
> 4. the tactical services
> 5. Joint IT

Examples:

> Today many IT services and systems are designed to work in a robust IT environment and often do not scale down to **the deployed user** ...
>
> It will facilitate mission accomplishment by providing **tactical services from the edge** in support of the warfighter ...
>
> ...recognizes all aspects of **Joint IT**...
>
> ...providing increased agility, and operational effects and capabilities for the warfighter **at the tactical edge**.

Comment: These are not military terms. They could equally be used in a non-military context.

Comment: Where did you find those examples? Generally it's better to cite your quotes so we can help you in your context, rather than providing you with a less specific (and hence possibly less helpful) generic answer.

Answer (score 2):

The document you are referring to, [*The Global Information Grid (GIG) 2.0 : Concept of Operations : Version 1.1*](http://info.publicintelligence.net/DoD-GIG2-CONOPS.pdf), describes an effort

> to evolve our information technology (IT)/ National Security Systems (NSS) services into a single information environment with common standards and centralized governance providing the 
>   information advantage to our warfighting commanders. This will improve command and control and increase our speed of action in combat.

Two central themes of the document are

- that current US military IT services do not adequately serve [*deployed*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deployed) users—the troops and units actually engaged in combat, who should be among the system’s principal clients. These are said to be *at the (tactical) edge*—that is, they are engaged in [tactical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tactical?q=tactical) rather than *strategic* operations at the ‘edge’: on the battle-line where the enemy is actually engaged.
- that US military IT services are fragmented, which inhibits proper coordination of the efforts of different services. This document calls for *Joint IT*, seen as a *coherent “Enterprise” that exists ultimately to 
  support the Combatant Commanders (CCDR) in their Joint Warfighting missions.*

Comment: +1 for the link to the document in the question. I would like to +2 more for making *at the tactical edge* become clear (which I couldn't for lacking for more context), and for mentioning the fine contrast of *tactical* and *strategic*. Unfortunately, I can upvote for each answer only once.

Answer (score 0):

When a software system is put into use, it is usually said the software is **deployed**.

So ***the deployed user*** should mean the user who use the deployed system. (I still wonder why they didn't write *users* instead. Perhaps, their system was designed for a single user.)

The word **edge** can mean advantage. According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=edge%20meaning),

> **edge** *noun*
>   - a quality or factor that gives superiority over close rivals or competitors

The word **tactical** can mean planned or strategic. According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tactical%20meaning),

> **tactical** *adjective*
>   1. of, relating to, or constituting actions carefully planned to gain a specific military end.

That should help you to understand ***from the edge***, ***tactical edge***, and ***the tactical services***.

As for ***Joint IT***, because the word Joint is capitalized, it is likely to be a proper name of some organization or some entity.

Comment: You explained a common sense. Look at last example. "Tactical edge" in military aspect is not only factor, that gives superority over competitors. It's rather like a... some place or state.

Comment: There are phrases like *cutting edge (technology)*, *leading edge*, or *bleeding edge*, meaning the latest or most advanced state of that kind of technology. It seems like the quote tries to convince that their technology is something cutting edge that will give the deployed user an edge (tactical one, to be specific) in the warfare.